# Knuth algorithm on constructing a proof

Tags: algorithms, induction, proof-explanation

I'm going through mathematical induction section of Knuth's book "[The Art of Computer Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201896834)" (pg. 11).  I'm having a hard time understanding Algorithm I on constructing a proof.  Here is the algorithm:

> I1. [Prove P(1).] Set $k \leftarrow$ 1, and, according to (a), output a proof of P(1). 
>   I2. [$k=n?$]  If $k=n$ terminate the algorithm; the required proof has been output. 
>  I3. [Prove P(k+1)] According to (b), output a proof that "If all of P(1),..., P(K) are true, then P(k+1) is true."  Also output "We have already proved P(1),...,P(k);hence P(k+1) is ture" 
>  I4. [Increase k.] Increase $k$ by 1 and go to step I2.

Here is (a) and (b) mentioned in the algorithm from the previous induction example in the book:

> a) Give a proof that P(1) is true 
>  b) Give a proof that "if all P(1), P(2),...,P(n) are true, then P(n+1) is also true"; this proof should be valid for any positive integer n.

There is a neat little diagram in the book illustrating the algorithm.

I am why confused about why the the algorithm cycles through all $k$ until $n$.  I thought when doing an induction proof you prove $P(k+1)$ once after proving the base case. Is this a simple brute force algorithm testing each k?  Why does it cycle through each k?

Comment: Presumably the book is trying to prove $P(n)$?

Comment: Yes, "Given a positive integer $n$, this algorithm will output a proof that $P(n)$ is true"

Comment: The two are equivalent, see for example [_complete induction_, _course of values induction_ or _strong induction_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction).

Comment: The point of this algorithm is that it provides a constructive way to see why induction works.  In essence, it is expanding out what is happening when one writes "...therefore by induction...".  Since this is the intent, it would make no sense to abbreviate the argument by *not* cycling through each $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $a)$ and $b)$ hold, the algorithm has to cycle through all $k$ up to $n$ because only two facts about $P(n)$ are known:

a) It holds for $P(1)$.

b) Given $P(k)$ holds, $P(k+1)$ also holds.

If you were to build a machine from these atomic principles, all you can do is to start at the (only known) true statement $P(1)$ and, successively, make your way through up to $n$.

Like in $P(16) = $ *There is an integer larger than 16*.

We start off at $P(1)$, which we already proved by means of $a)$ by noting that the community agreed on $2 > 1$. Computer says:

```
P(1) holds since 2 > 1.
```

Computer checks if $1 = 16$, which is not the case, branching into a proof for $P(2)$. Since we've already done all the work prior to designing the machine by giving a proof for $b)$, the machine simply outputs:

```
If all of P(1) are true, then P(2) is true.
We have already proved P(1); hence P(2) is true.
```

Consecutively, the counter is incremented, test for end carried out and the machine keeps going on until it reaches $k = 16$.

Admittedly, this is a no-brainer and to us it seems pointless to put any effort in designing (and maintaining) a machine that is hardly more than a counter. But if you had no chance whatsoever for reasoning, the only way for you, as a machine, to guarantee that $P(n)$ holds, is to go through every single step.